# Issue with split field parsing

Tags: perl, parsing, text

I am reading a txt file line by line. Columns are separated via a ";" separator and the file is similar to the one below.

```
text;10.1.1.1;description
text;10.1.1.2;description
...
text;10.1.1.90;description
```

Perl code:

```
@splitted=split(";",$line)
$description=$splitted[2];
```

I am facing a weird situation when reading the last field (Description).
this field it's not read correctly, and I can see the issue when doing a text comparison but even more evidently when printing the $description

If I

```
print ":$description:"
```

(I am using : as a delimiter to see if there are any spaces before and after the string), I can see that the actual strings eats up even the Quotes, or whatever string there is before that phrase:

Literally:

Instead of :

```
"The value of description is :abcdef:"
```

I get

```
"The value of descripabcdef"
```

**The problem is resolved by putting a delimiter also at the end of the line: IE:**

```
text;10.1.1.1;description;
text;10.1.1.2;description;
...
text;10.1.1.90;description;
```

I hope I was able to make the point clear.
Many thanks,
Francesco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the file was created on a Mac and the line-ending character is a single `\r`.

You probably did not remove it (`chomp` in Perl).  What's happening is that the output is complete but the embedded `\r` is causing later text to overwrite earlier output.

Another possibility is that the file was created on Windows (line ending is `\r\n`) and you are processing this on a system where the line ending is only `\n`.  In that case, `chomp` would remove the `\n` but leave the `\r` at the end of the line.

You should remove all trailing whitespace from the line before splitting it. I.e.

```
s/\s+$//
```

Comment: Thank you jim, I did use chomp, both on the eniter line and the single/string. nothing change.

Comment: Yes, it does work. Great intuition. So this Reg Ex is maching one or more spaces (s+) at the end of the line, right? Many thanks again.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, and replacing the matched string with nothing.